# Can Nullity Be Used to Show That Nullspace is a Basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can I show that the nullspace of a matrix is a basis by finding the nullity?

For example, given matrix **A**, I can find the nullspace of the matrix, which is the span of a set of vectors. I can also find the nullity of **A** (the dimension of the nullspace of **A**) by reducing A to Reduced Echelon Form and counting the number of free variables.

If the nullity of **A** is equal to the number of vectors that span the nullspace of **A**, can I say that those vectors spanning the nullspace is a basis of the nullspace?

EDIT* comment from @Niing

Comment: By definition, nullity is the dimension of the nullspace. And yes any spanning set containing exactly dimension-number of vectors is the basis of the spanned vector space. This can be proved.

Comment: But you meant the null space is a basis of what?

Comment: @Niing the nullspace would then also be the basis for the nullspace I suppose?

Comment: Ok now I get your error, it's "those vectors span the nullspace is a basis of the nullspace", not "nullspace is a basis"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. For $n$ dimensional vector space $V$, any set of $n$ vectors that span the set is a basis and it's rather easy to prove.

*Hint: Take a basis of $V$ and use replacement theorem.*